# Relacionar chaves estrangeiras distintas em uma coluna?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core, chave-estrangeira

Olá,

Estou criando uma tabela para cadastrar materiais ou serviços que dependem de outras duas tabelas para formar o seu centro de custo (foreign key), dependendo do tipo do cadastro.

Se for cadastrar um material, vou usar a tabela CatMatPdm no foreign key, se for um serviço, vou usar a tabela CatSerServicos.

Atualmente uso duas foreign key distintas para relacionar as tabelas.

```
public class CatMatMaterial
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public int CatMatPdmId { get; set; }
    public CatMatPdm CatMatPdm { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MaterialServico> MateriaisServicos { get; set; }
}

public class CatSerServico
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public int CatSerGrupoId { get; set; }
    public CatSerGrupo CatSerGrupo { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MaterialServico> MateriaisServicos { get; set; }
}

public class MaterialServico
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public Boolean GerenciarEstoque { get; set; }
    public float ValorUnitario { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    (...)

    public int CatSerServicoId { get; set; }
    public CatSerServico CatSerServico { get; set; }

    public int CatMatMaterialId { get; set; }
    public CatMatMaterial CatMatMaterial { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

Quando vou inserir no banco de dados tenho que verificar o tipo de cadastro que vai ser (material ou serviço) para depois escolher em qual foreign key vai ser inserido.

O fato de fazer essa escolha e ter duas foreign key para o mesmo objetivo está me deixando incomodado e faz pensar que exista uma forma mais limpa e fácil de montar esse relacionamento.

Já pensei em criar uma coluna sem relacionamento (foreign key) e inserir o CatMatMaterialId e o CatMatServicoId nela, mas eu poderia ter um problema futuro, caso deletasse um item do centro de custo (CatMatMaterial / CatSerServico) e por algum infortúnio fosse deletado sem conferir o relacionamento (preciso de um DeleteBehavior.

Não consigo imaginar ou encontrar uma forma de ter um relacionamento entre essas tabelas de forma mais eficiente e por isso preciso da ajuda de vocês para saber se existe uma forma melhor de mapear esse relacionamento.

Utilizo o Entity Framework Core 2.2.1 e o PostgreSQL.

PS: Infelizmente tenho que usar dois centros de custo distintos para materiais e serviços, pois é assim que o governo federal utiliza...

Obrigado

Comment: Não tenho ideia de como fazer no framework que você utiliza. Em termos de banco de dados isto normalmente é modelado como um particionamento da entidade e cada partição com seu relacionamento específico.

Comment: Que restrições vc tem para alterar as tabelas ? Se poderis ter um campo único com as validações em triggers tanto para a fk , quanto para a deleção de uma fk (um serviço pex) qq solução porem vai demandar depois sqls complicadas , union etc. Expluque melhor esta restrição das duas tabelas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que ter a seguinte organização de classes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A classe CatalogoBase é ancestral às que você usa como entidade estrangeira. Poderia ter a seguinte configuração:

```
public class CatalogoBase {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MaterialServico> MateriaisServicos { get; set; }
}
```

As classes que herdam da classe CatalogoBase são os catálogos CatMatMaterial e CatSerServicos,

```
public class CatMatMaterial : CatalogoBase {
    public int CatMatPdmId { get; set; }
    public virtual CatMatPdm CatMatPdm { get; set; }
}

public class CatSerServico : CatalogoBase {
    public int CatSerGrupoId { get; set; }
    public virtual CatSerGrupo CatSerGrupo { get; set; }
}
```

e a classe agregadora é a MaterialServico,

```
public class MaterialServico {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public Boolean GerenciarEstoque { get; set; }
    public float ValorUnitario { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    (...)

    [ForeignKey("Catalogo")]
    public int IdCatalogo { get; set; }

    public virtual CatalogoBase Catalogo { get; set; }
}
```

Uma provável consulta que você poderá querer fazer é a seguinte,

```
...
var materialOuServico =
    dbContext.MaterialServico.Find(57).Catalogo;

if (materialOuServico is CatMatMaterial) {
    var material = materialOuServico as CatMatMaterial;
    // Processa material.
}

if (materialOuServico is CatSerServico) {
    var servico = materialOuServico as CatSerServico;
    // Processa serviço.
}
```

Comment: Chamei a tabela ancestral de `Catalogo` porque fiquei cismado com o _Cat_..., mas poderia ser qualquer nome. Caso tenha alguma dúvida, pode perguntar.